# Event bus implementations with Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, asp.net, azureservicebus, event-bus

Look, I'm needing an example of how to implement Event bus implementations with Azure Service Bus, took a look at [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers). But I only saw it with Rabbit. I would like to know how I set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Quick start for Azure Service Bus that covers [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) and [Topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quickstart-topics-subscriptions-portal).

---

The project [dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) works not just with RabbitMQ but with Azure Service Bus too.
See [Switch to Azure Service Bus](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/master/readme/README.ENV.md#azure-service-bus-service).

---

Look at [Azure Service Bus .NET Framework samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging).

> This repository contains the official set of samples for the Azure
>   Service Bus service (Standard and Premium), illustrating all core
>   features of Service Bus **queues** and Service Bus **topics**. This samples
>   all use the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus NuGet package for the full .NET
>   Framework.

Comment: OK, Iooked for Event Bus Service Bus, but not found

Comment: I checked eShopOnContainers-project and it turns out it supports Azure Service Bus - my answer was updated.

Comment: I'm sorry,I not understanding this example. I need basicalle sample  https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/rabbitmq-event-bus-development-test-environment

Comment: It is OK, I added to answer the links to Quick Start for Queue & Topic.